# Is it possible to open and flip through a Keynote in my own IOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, powerpoint, keynote

So I had a amazing idea for a app that involves Keynotes/Powerpoints. I figured there would almost certainly be 100s of threads on how to do this natively in a app or at the very least a few solid libraries built to do this on Github, but so far based on the research ive done so far it appears its either not possible, is so ridiculously hard no ones dared to ever attempt it or im missing something? If this is the case ....why? Is it a silly Apple rule or something?

Just to be 1000% clear, I want to open the presentation IN MY OWN APP, I DO NOT want to just to deep link over to keynote, my app has to be the app that the viewer can view the keynote from and flip through the slides from.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Look at using `UIWebView` it's really useful for handling different document formats like pdf, keynote, pages, excel e.t.c. It's good for viewing, not editing.

Comment: I want to open a keynote inside my ios app (not deeplink to keynote)

Answer (score 0):

WebViews within your app, accessing the Keynote iCloud presentation, with edit ability set by the owner of the file. That's as good as this is going to get without making custom parser to present .key files with a native rendering engine (also custom made).